# Copy a worksheet to a new workbook with paste values and keeping formats

Tags: vba, format, copy, worksheet

I am trying to copy one worksheet to a new workbook, pasting all formulas as values while remaining all formats, sheetname, etcetera. The new file name should be "University" and stored on the same location as the original file.
I have been struggling with this, as it keeps returning an

> "Error 1004: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

with my current (copied) script:

```
Sub new_workbook()

Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "University.xlsx"
Output.SaveAs FileName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet.Copy` with no *Before* or *After* specified creates a new workbook, so just work off of that.

More detail from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy):

> If you don't specify either *Before* or *After*, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied `Worksheet` object. The newly created workbook holds the `Application.ActiveWorkbook` property and contains a single worksheet.

```
Sub new_workbook()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Copy '<-- creates a new workbook with a copy of your sheet

    Dim Output as Workbook
    Set Output = ActiveWorkbook

    With Output.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value '<-- changes all formulas to values
    End With

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\University.xlsx"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Output.SaveAs FileName

End Sub
```

Comment: Fabulous, that was quick!