# How to save only one worksheet as a different workbook in excel using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a worksheet as a different workbook and I am doing that within a loop because the worksheet is updating every time. How do I manage to do that. I have used following code but it will copy other worksheets too.

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    xRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To xRow
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetToCopy")
   //doing something in the sheet

   fname = .Range("B22").Text & " - " & .Range("B24").Text & ".xlsm"
   End With
  .SaveAs filename:=PATH & fname
     Next I
  End With
```

Comment: `Copy` the worksheet w/o specifying any parameters, and then save the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you. That will save all the sheets. I want to save only one. Can you please explain?

Comment: No it won't... `Copy` w/o specifying any parameters creates a new workbook with only one sheet.... literally just demonstrated the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326725/copy-a-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook-with-paste-values-and-keeping-formats)

Comment: What could be the parameter? And what is w/o?

Comment: `w/o` = `without`.

Comment: It says: can not use this property or method: With Output.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value '<-- changes all formulas to values
    End With

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question with the revised code you are using

Comment: @BigBen, I just had to move around the declarations. Thanks. Its working now